# Focusrite Scarlett 6i6 hard times

Tags: sound, ubuntu-studio, jack, external-soundcard

The answers to this question that are all around the forums already outdated.

I'm running a clean install of Ubuntu Studio 15.10. With Jack Control or aplay -l I can see it's there. But I can get no sounds from the audio interface.

The Focusrite website says it should work. The Scarlett 2i2 is well known to work easily and flawless. But there are a lot of post asking about how to make the 6i6 work in Linux. The answers are from turning wifi off (which I did) to installing new kernel (which I don't need)

Any directions out there?

best regards,
skmecs

Comment: I upvoted this question, hoping someone would answer it, but unfortunately nobody has. I'm considering getting a Focusrite, and using Ubuntu Studio with it. I found the information in the following link interesting. Worth checking out if you haven't. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2309922

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the link theodorn

Answering myself, here's a direction if anyone out there is having the same problem.

I tried KXStudio running it from the USB-stick. It worked! I could have sound coming from the audio interface. So I installed it.
I would rather stay on Ubuntu Studio, though.

bests,
skmecs

editing for future reference:
I could solve most of the problems I had using somehing rather old: the Gnome Alsa Mixer.
So I could use Ubuntu Studio smoothly.
I'm sorry I didn't follow the good practices protocol of when I posted this issue, but the problems I had seams to be already solved at the present moment.

Comment: Great, thanks for telling. I adore Ubuntu Studio, been using 15.10 a few months. Do check out 16.04 in late April, on a live USB or a separate partition. I'm not sure a virtual machine would work well in audio processing.

Comment: I just used the live USB, directly from the USB stick, to check if I would make KXStudio work with my piece of hardware.

I like Ubuntu Studio a lot too. It would be great to have a tool in it that with the same flexibility that Cadenze offers in KXStudio.

Anyway I think this post should be marked as solved. I think I don't have the privileges to do it.

Comment: You can accept your own answer 48 hours after you answered. You don't gain reputation, but it is a signal that the issue is solved. It doesn't put the [SOLVED] mark to the title of the question automatically. If a question has [SOLVED] in the title, it has been inserted manually. Doing is so is actually not recommended. http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7413/attaching-solved-to-title-of-questions-with-accepted-answers