# Ubuntu 16.04 and Focusrite Scarlett 6i6

Tags: pulseaudio, 16.04, alsa, live-cd

Ubuntu 16.04 can't see my Focusrite Scarlett 6i6 connection. 
Alsa mixer doesn't get any device. But on LiveCD Ubuntu 16.04 it works. Also full installation of Ubuntu 16.04 from LiveCD was without any updates.
On Ubuntu 15.10 it worked without issues. Any ideas about properly connection on Ubuntu 16.04?

Following link I found:
[Focusrite Scarlett 6i6 hard times](https://askubuntu.com/questions/738559/focusrite-scarlett-6i6-hard-times) 
but right know I can't use kxstudio, also not shure about kxstudio for 16.04